# How to fasten spark dataframe write to hive table in ORC store

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hive, orc

```
thirdCateBrandres.createOrReplaceTempView("tempTable2")
sql("insert overwrite table temp_cate3_Brand_List select * from tempTable2")
```

The code as above, `thirdCateBrandres` is a spark `DataFrame`, registered as a temp table,then write to table `temp_cate3_Brand_List`, the table has 3 billion row with 7 fields, data size is about 4GB in ORC+SNAPPY format .
These codes took about 20 minutes.

***How can  I speed up the program?***